# Sometimes the Tkinter canvas doesn't load

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am writing a program which involves drawing rectangles on the tkinter canvas. Here is the code that creates the canvas and the window it is a part of. (This is within an object, and the root.mainloop() is called later outside of the object, and the drawing is also present elsewhere)

```
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.title = "Game"
    self.root.resizable(0,0)
    self.root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 500))

    #create drawing canvas
    self.canvas_base = tk.Canvas(self.root, bg="white", width=500, height=500)

    self.canvas_base.bind("<Up>", lambda event1, arg1=0: self.arrow_press(event1,arg1)) #bind up key
    self.canvas_base.bind("<Right>", lambda event2, arg2=1: self.arrow_press(event2,arg2)) #bind right key
    self.canvas_base.bind("<Down>", lambda event3, arg3=2: self.arrow_press(event3,arg3)) #bind down key
    self.canvas_base.bind("<Left>", lambda event4, arg4=3: self.arrow_press(event4,arg4)) #bind left key
    self.canvas_base.focus_set()  #give the window keyboard focus

    self.canvas_base.pack()
```

The problem I've noticed is that sometimes no canvas is generated, as the white background fails to appear and I'm left with the grey/off-white basic background for the window. No errors pop up in the console, and other code within the window runs fine. Is this a normal problem with the canvas, or is it something to do with the code?

Considering the size of my code, and the fact that I have no idea what is exactly causing the issue. I decided to just post the main initialization, but if the drawing/anything else within the code would have an impact, I can post that too. Also, nothing else is being done with the canvas.

EDIT:

This seems to occur with the creation of the canvas full stop, and is probably a Python error. By running similar code as the entirety of a file, and waiting a period before I run it each time, the first time I run it after an hour or so causes no Canvas to appear.

Comment: the default background for tkinter - as far as I know - is white, so if there is grey I'd suggest checking that you are not drawing something grey by accident. Either way this code segment doesn't have anything to do with the problem you are describing.

Comment: It's a bug in your code somewhere. Since we can't see the code it's going to be impossible for us to help you.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen It's not exactly grey, but I can't describe the co lour. It's just not quite white, and I can notice the difference. I am only drawing black objects. Also, there has been an update.

Comment: It is almost certainly not "a python error". Python and tkinter are well tested by thousands of people over the course of many years. Of course, no software is 100% bug free, but it's highly unlikely that you've triggered a bug in python itself.